# Insert two Records in new mysql table for each record in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I need to Insert two Records in a new mysql table for each record in another table
example:

table1

```
id, name 
1, Patrick
2, John
```

I want to insert favorite site for each records in the second table and each record should have facebook and google as default

the second table should looks like:
table2

```
table1_id, site
1, facebook
1, google
2, facebook
2, google
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can multiply the original table with a fixed list of rows with a `cross join`:

```
insert into table2 (table1_id, site)
select t1.id, s.site
from table1 t1
cross join (select 'google' site union all select 'facebook') s
```

In recent MySQL versions (>= 8.0.19), [the `VALUES` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) makes the syntax neater:

```
insert into table2 (table1_id, site)
select t1.id, s.site
from table1 t1
cross join ( values row('google'), row('facebook') ) s(site)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using `inner join`

```
insert into table2
select t1.id, s.site
from table1 t1
inner join (
  select 'facebook' site union select 'google' site
) as s on s.site <> ''
order by t1.id;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6OzU6oGJ)